# Decrypt and stream video

Tags: javascript, encryption

The situation I need help with is as follows.

I have a video file that is encrypted with "aes-256-ctr" algo on a URL.
I have a JS web app that needs to play the video.
The file can range from a 10 MBs to a 4 GBs.

I do not want to download the complete file and then decrypt it and display from the locally decrypted file. And obviously I can not give the URL to the video tag as it will no be able to play the file.

Is there a way that the stream can be decrypted and displayed?

I am not sure how to handle this situation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to decrypt and stream your video on the fly ? thanks !

Comment: Hi,@Yuukuari sorry for the late reply. 
Yes, I Used pipe to get the stream and pass to on to the decryption function and then pipe it onto the response.
request(url).pipe(decrypt).pipe(response);